# How can I create a transparent user control in WPF?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, wpf-controls, transparency

I have a WPF app with an image over which is laid a user control. I would like the user control background to be transparent but the buttons etc on that user control to be solid.

The image below shows what I have now. I would like to have the inside of the red area as transparent (the user control can in theory be many different shapes) but with the controls contained within it, solid.

[image]

The main window XAML is;

```
<Canvas Height="450" Width="300">
    <Border Opacity=".2" >
        <Image Source="D:\\BarbourCoat.jpg" Width="300" ></Image>
    </Border>
    <local:UserControl1 Height="100" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Width="100"/>
</Canvas>
```

Whilst the user control XAML is;

```
<Canvas Background="Transparent">
    <Path Data="M 10 10 L 100 10 L 250 50 L 280 200 L 180 250 L 25 270 Z" Stroke="Red"></Path>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="41,53,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="90,112,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="69,209,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Canvas>
```

I'm having a hard time getting my head round this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In XAML, have you made the whole UserControl transparent?

`<UserControl
Background="Transparent">`

Comment: I have now, but it won't 'see through' the border element above, that's the bit that I think is the core of the problem.

Comment: I also think I have a problem with the Path, the inside needs clearing, I might be able to use a ClippingMask.

Comment: @RyanO'Neill Set the `Opacity` of either your `Path` object or your `UserControl` if you want it to be semi-transparent